# Search bar not displaying correctly in SSL

Tags: ssl, display

One portion of my website is not adjusting to SSL conversion.
the original non ssl site is www.methowrealestateservices.com
the site that is not displaying correctly, the search bar across the banner is https://methowrealestateservices.com
I am not sure how to fix this. Can someone help?
I just have the one website, that I created, winging it all the way and the one component I got someone else to create, well of course that is the one piece that is not working.  The omni bar has the info to its classes and what have you in the folder idxforge on the host server, and I can get that all posted too if it makes a difference.It is in methowrealestateservices.com/idxforge...

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed content in your website. Some JS are referenced to be loaded with http scheme.  You have to update that.